# decomposition of m-cycle in m-1 transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

I am searching for a proof. Every m-cycle $\sigma = (x_1 x_2 ... x_m)$ can be expressed as an composition of m-1 transpositions.

I found many formulas, for example:

$\sigma = (x_1 x_2)(x_2 x_3) ... (x_{m-1} x_m)$

$\sigma = (x_1 x_2)(x_1 x_3) ... (x_1 x_m)$

and I see how they are m-1 transpositions. But I haven't found any proof of these formulas. They are all kind of presumed. Also presumed is that every cycle can be written as composition of disjoint cycles.

Can somebody help me, how to get to these formulas?

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the second product of 2-cycles, and note that you are composing permutations left-to-right.

You start with $x_1$, and notice it is sent to $x_2$ by the first 2-cycle, and then $x_2$ does not appear in any of the other cycles, so $\sigma$ maps $x_1$ to $x_2$.

Now consider $x_2$. It is sent to $x_1$ by the first 2-cycle, which is then sent to $x_3$ by the second cycle. No other cycles contain $x_3$, so $\sigma$ maps $x_2$ to $x_3$.

In general, note first that all $x_i$ except $x_1$ occur only once in one of the 2-cycles. If $1 < i < m$, note first that that $x_{i}$ occurs in the $(i-1)$-th 2-cycle, which sends it to $x_1$. The next cycle sends $x_1$ to $x_{i+1}$, so $\sigma$ maps $x_{i}$ to $x_{i+1}$. When $i = m$, just note that the last cycle sends it to $x_1$.